# Issue with Game Maker Export

Tags: android, game-engine, game-maker, game-maker-studio-1.4

I have been having an issue with exporting my project to an APK, I have all the required SDK, and I have installed the Google API required for Game Maker, but this error continues to occur.

```
BUILD FAILED C:\Android\SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:538: Unable to resolve project target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:13'
```

I have the SDK installed, along with the API 13, as you can see below

[Installed API](https://prnt.sc/k40rq9)

There is no other solution I can think of, I have tried reinstalling multiple times, it doesn't work. Below is my Android settings for Game Maker.

[Game Maker Settings](http://prntscr.com/k40t8s)

Game Maker 1.4 uses Android 2.3 for exporting APKs, which is why I haven't installed any other version APIs
If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update GMS. This issue solved long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Dmi7ry, update GMS 1.4 to the latest version. Reading from Mantis, they've fixed this.

Also, all issues referencing this link to this guide to follow: https://forum.yoyogames.com/index.php?threads/notes-about-getting-the-android-module-to-work-for-gms-version-1-4-1763-as-of-may-1-2017.16061/.